# Accessing methods from an external script in Angular 2 +

Tags: angular

I have a minified js file that contains a whole bunch of methods and is loaded via the scripts array inside of angular.json. I can reference the methods from the developer console but how can I access them from one of my components? Or is there a better way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added external libraries via the scripts array of angular.json file - all methods of that library become available automatically from any place in your code.

If you faced the issue that your IDE warns you about unknown variables and methods you can just use this simple overround:

Assume that you have added some library which has global variable or method `myThing`.

Now in your angular component, in the imports section write:

```
declare let myThing: any; // available globally
```

Now you should not receive warnings from IDE and typescript, but will be able to access that thing successfuly.